# Vue js project not loading .env variables

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am working on a Vue JS project. I made a .env file in the project's root directory. I made 3 variables. Here is the content of my .env:

```
API_BASE_URL=http://x.x.x.x:yyyy/myproject
VUE_APP_TITLE=My App
VUE_MY_VAR=My Var
```

I put the logs inside the component that loads on startup in beforeMount() method like this:

```
beforeMount() {
            console.log('base url: ' + process.env.API_BASE_URL);
            console.log('base url: ' + process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE);
            console.log('base url: ' + process.env.VUE_MY_VAR);
        }
```

When I run dev server using `vue-cli-service serve` I see the following console output:

```
base url: undefined
base url: My App
base url: undefined
```

My question is: why is the value of A`PI_BASE_URL` and `VUE_MY_VAR` undefined

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html):

> Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

So you need to add `VUE_APP_` prefix to your variables.

Comment: I'll also add that you *may* need to completely stop and restart your localhost so your app can pick up the changes.

Comment: Ah god. I was really frustrated as what really is wrong with my environment variable :)